# Retrieving Image (Base64String) from Windows Azure Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, base64, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

**How do I retrieve the image that I stored as Base64String in Windows Azure? I know how to save the image as Base64String in Windows Azure but I have no clue on how to retrieve it.**

Saving Data to Windows Azure Storage as Base64String:

```
  private MemoryStream str;

  str = new MemoryStream();

  WriteableBitmap wb;

  wb = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);

  wb.SaveJpeg(str, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

  Item item = new Item { ImageString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(str.ToArray()) };

  App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>().InsertAsync(item);
```

Class:

```
 public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageString { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the image by the id (which will be returned after the call to `InsertAsync`):

```
private void RetrieveImage(int id) {
    var item = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>().LookupAsync(id);
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(item.ImageString);
}
```

Or to retrieve all images:

```
private void RetrieveAllImages() {
    var images = await App.MobileService
        .GetTable<Item>()
        .Select(i => Convert.FromBase64String(i.ImageString))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Or to query using an arbitrary property (instead of the id) - assuming the Item class has a property called 'Name':

```
var items = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>()
    .Where(it => it.Name == "MyImage")
    .ToEnumerableAsync();
var item = item.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: One more thing, how do I query it using a string instead of an id?

Comment: Updated the answer with the query option - use the `Where` method.